# How to use @Bindable in child POJO?

Tags: android, android-databinding

I made a layout that must be used for 2 POJO. So i created an Interface like this:

```
public interface GameItemParent {
  ...
  boolean isChecked();
}
```

One of child classes:

```
public class FavoriteGame implements GameItemParent,Observable {
  @SerializedName(SerCons.C_CHECKED) private int checked;

  private PropertyChangeRegistry registry = new PropertyChangeRegistry();

  public FavoriteGame() {
  }

  @Bindable public boolean isChecked() {
    return checked == 1;
  }

  public void setChecked(boolean checked, boolean notifyObserver) {
    this.checked = checked ? 1 : 0;
    if (notifyObserver)
      registry.notifyChange(this, BR.checked);
  }

  public void inverseChecked() {
    setChecked(!isChecked(), true);
  }

  @Override public void addOnPropertyChangedCallback(OnPropertyChangedCallback callback) {
    registry.add(callback);
  }

  @Override public void removeOnPropertyChangedCallback(OnPropertyChangedCallback callback) {
    registry.remove(callback);
  }
  ...
}
```

the XML file that listens to 'isChecked' changes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    >
  <data>
    <import type="android.view.View"/>
    <variable
        name="game"
        type="com.consoleco.console.objectParents.GameItemParent"
        />
  </data>
  <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
      .../>
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatCheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="@{game.checked}"
        android:visibility="@{game.hasCheckButton() ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}"
        app:buttonTint="?attr/colorAccent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/icon"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/icon"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/icon"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/icon"
        />
  </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

As you noticed, I declared 'GameItemParent' interface as 'game' data. Because I have to use this XML for another child too.

Now when I change 'isChecked' at runtime, the UI (actually the checkbox) doesn't get change.

Comment: Why are you not using `BaseObservable`

Comment: Because I extended children from another parent and cannot use inheritance

Comment: Then you can make the parent class only extending `BaseObservable`?

Comment: I can't extend parent class from BaseObservable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `GameItemParent` is a simple interface and therefore the binding library only knows about the property itself. It should be working, when it also extends the `Observable`:

```
public interface GameItemParent extends Observable {
    ...
    @Bindable boolean isChecked();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I did this before (and add addOnPropertyChangedCallback,... in child class). But not works.

Comment: Did you also add the `@Bindable` annotation to `isChecked()`?

Comment: My apologize. Your solution worked. The problem was with this function:

public void inverseChecked() { setChecked(isChecked(), true); }.